# Time complexity of one algorithm cascaded into another?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, k-means, random-forest

I am working with random forest for a supervised classification problem, and I am using the k-means clustering algorithm to split the data at each node. I am trying to calculate the time complexity for the algorithm. From what I understand the the time complexity for k-means is

> O(n · K · I · d )

where

- n is the number of points,
- K is the number of clusters,
- I is the number of iterations, and
- d is the number of attributes.

The k, I and d are constants or have an upper bound, and n is much larger as compared to these three, so I suppose the complexity is just O(n).

The random forest, on the other hand, is a divide-and-conquer approach, so for n instances the complexity is O(n · logn), though I am not sure about this, correct me if i am wrong.

To get the complexity of the algorithm do i just add these two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you don't add the values together. If you have a divide-and-conquer algorithm, the runtime is determined by a combination of

- The number of subproblems made per call,
- The sizes of those subproblems, and
- The amount of work done per problem.

Changing any one of these parameters can wildly impact the overall runtime of the function. If you increase the number of subproblems made per call by even a small amount, you increase exponentially the number of total subproblems, which can have a large impact overall. Similarly, if you increase the work done per level, since there are so many subproblems the runtime can swing wildly.  Check out the Master Theorem as an example of how to determine the runtime based on these quantities.

In your case, you are beginning with a divide-and-conquer algorithm where all you know is that the runtime is O(n log n) and are adding in a step that does O(n) work per level. Just knowing this, I don't believe it's possible to determine what the runtime will be. If, on the other hand, you make the assumption that

- The algorithm always splits the input into two smaller pieces,
- The algorithm recursively processes those two pieces independently, and
- The algorithm uses your O(n) algorithm to determine which split to make

Then you can conclude that the runtime is O(n log n), since this is the solution to the recurrence given by the Master Theorem.

Without more information about the internal workings of the algorithm, though, I can't say for certain.

Hope this helps!